# User Profile Edit workflow

Tags: users, workflows

any module available, to implement a work flow when user is trying edit the user profile fileds (custom fields). Following is my use case

1) User can edit the profile field , but admin approval is required to update it 
2) Admin can either approve or reject the profile update 
3) If it is approved need to change the user role , and need to send an email to the user 
4) If rejected , need to trigger an email again

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is need to work with Rules module make such action, "send email", "change role".

The [workbench module](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) is very popular, but is for Drupal 7 only. can be achieved good results using the [revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) module, which has a release for Drupal 6.

Comment: I don't think workbench works with user profiles, though. By default user profiles done't have revisions, though there's [a module](http://drupal.org/project/user_revision) which adds that functionality.